# sizing the layout in android

Tags: android-layout

I have exactly 5 buttons in my layout. The problem i am facing while displaying the layout is - the remaining space of the layout is being wasted rather is empty. I wanted to reduce the screen size so that it didn't look half-way blank.

Following is the code i have written in the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <!-- I want to eat button -->
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/iWantToEat"
    android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/iWantToEat">
    </Button>

    <!-- Categories -->
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/Categories"
    android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/Categories">
    </Button>

    <!-- Explore/Discover -->
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/Explore"
    android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/Explore">
    </Button>

    <!-- Search -->
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/Search"
    android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/Search">
    </Button>

    <!-- My Favorites -->
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/myFavourites"
    android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/myFavourites">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to achieve it ?

Adithya.

Comment: i didnt understand......you want the 5 buttons to fill the entire screen??

Comment: no..i want to have these buttons of their specific size only ( say 20sp) but want the screen size to reduce so that the layout shows only these 5 buttons and no blank space is left in the layout as it will normally do below those buttons.

Comment: so you can have spaces between the buttons...

Comment: should i add empty textviews ? or is there a better approach ?

Comment: you can have spaces between buttons.....reply then i can help u

Comment: sure..let me know..but still even if i have spaces how will it resolve my problem ? i mean for every android phone this is not a solution i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

First make the root LinearLayout height to ***fill_parent*** so that it fills the entire screen

Then put the buttons inside another LinearLayout with **android:layout_weight="1"** as shown below

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
         <!-- I want to eat button -->
        <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/iWantToEat">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

It divide the screen to 1:1:1:1:1 ratio